# Strip or Regex function in Spark 1.3 Dataframe

Tags: regex, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have some code from PySpark 1.5 that I unfortunately have to port backwards to Spark 1.3. I have a column with elements that are alpha-numeric but I only want the digits.
An example of the elements in 'old_col' of 'df' are:

```
 '125 Bytes'
```

In Spark 1.5 I was able to use

```
df.withColumn('new_col',F.regexp_replace('old_col','(\D+)','').cast("long"))
```

However, I cannot seem to come up with a solution using old 1.3 methods like SUBSTR or RLIKE. Reason being the number of digits in front of "Bytes" will vary in length, so what I really need is the 'replace' or 'strip' functionality I can't find in Spark 1.3
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you use `HiveContext` you can execute corresponding Hive UDFs either with `selectExpr`:

```py
df.selectExpr("regexp_extract(old_col,'([0-9]+)', 1)")
```

or with plain SQL:

```py
df.registerTempTable("df")
sqlContext.sql("SELECT regexp_extract(old_col,'([0-9]+)', 1) FROM df")
```