# pyspark not working with regex

Tags: regex, pyspark

I've made RDD from a file with list of urls:

```
url_data = sc.textFile("url_list.txt")
```

Now i'm trying to make another RDD with all rows that contain 'net.com' and this string starts with non numeric or letter symbol. I mean include lines with .net.com or `\t`net.com and exclude internet.com or cnet.com.

```
filtered_data = url_data.filter(lambda x: '[\W]net\.com' in x)
```

But this line gives no results. 
How can i make pyspark shell work with regex?

Comment: `'[\W]net\.com' in '.net.com'` returns False in python. So, it's a python issue not a pyspark issue

Comment: any clue what correct regular expression would be?

Comment: \.+[a-zA-Z]+\.com looks like the regex command you want (test here: http://regexr.com/). But it doesn't seamlessly integrate in python like you need. It looks like you may be able to use this in an SQL query (example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34952985/strip-or-regex-function-in-spark-1-3-dataframe)

Comment: @lacerated: Did you try `r"\Wnet\.com"`? Does that also throw any errors? Actually, the regex `[\W]net\.com` works well in Python: http://ideone.com/kx8U3V

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Yep tried `r"\Wnet\.com"` too. I get no errors when i try to execute an action like `filtered_data.take(1)` just an empty string `[]`. If i try `filtered_data.first()` it says: `ValueError: RDD is empty`. Wonder if i need to import some pyspark module to make reg expressions work in spark like `import re` in python. If i do just `filtered_data = url_data.filter(lambda x: 'net.com' in x)` it filters just fine but i get extra lines i don`t need.

Answer (score 2):

Why not define a function in python that uses the re or re2 (much faster) package, and returns a Bool if there is a match.

```
def url_filter(url):
    pattern = re.compile(r'REGEX_PATTERN')
    match = pattern.match(URL)
    if match:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Then just pass it in to filter function `url_data.filter(lambda x: python_regex_fuction(x))`